# how to set default value in django template

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

i'm trying to set default value to an input field in django template , i have two models `tables`

```
class Ticketing(models.Model):
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    b = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2)
    #others

class Cancel(models.Model):
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticketing,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="ticket")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    #others
```

forms.py

```
class CancelForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta:
        model = Cancel
        fields = ['title',]
```

my views.py

```
def create_cancel(request,id):
    booking_obj = get_object_or_404(Ticketing,id=id)
    form = CancelForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CancelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.admin = request.user
            obj.ticket= booking_obj
            obj.save()
            return redirect('cancel:create' ,booking_obj.id)

     context = {
    '    booking_obj':booking_obj,'form':form
     }
     return render(request,'cancel/create.html',context)
```

urls

```
path('create/<int:id>',create_cancel,name='create'),
path('ajax/check-title/<int:id>',create_cancel,name='check_title'),
```

i tried to call back `title` using ajax but it doesnt work

```
@login_required
def check_invoice_paid(request,id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Ticketing,id=id)
    data = {
       'title':obj.title
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

my template

```js
        $('select').change(function() {
            let elm = $(this);
            data = {};
            data[elm.attr("name")] = elm.val();
            $.ajax({
                url:'{% url 'cancel:check_title' booking_obj.id %}',
                data:data,
                success:function(data){
                    if (data.title){
                        elm.closest("div.ticket ").find("input.title").val(data.title);
                    }


                    }

                }
            )
        })
```

```html
            <form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
                {{form.errors}}
                <div id="printDv" class="text-lg">
                    <p class="p-2 header rounded-lg text-center text-white">Cancel</p>
                    <div class="border border-purple-900 mt-2 rounded-lg p-2 text-center">
                        <p>no. : {{booking_obj.id}}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="ticket border border-purple-900 mt-2 text-center rounded-lg p-2 grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-1 gap-3" dir="ltr" >
                        <p>{{form.title | add_class:'title bg-transparent focus:outline-none w-8/12' }} :title</p>
         
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                <button class="header pt-2  text-white px-4 p-1 rounded-lg mt-4">save</button>
            </form>
```

but still doesnt work ! is there something i did wrong ?

im trying to set `booking_obj.title` as default value for `title` input in the `Cancel` model
thank you for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an initial object to the form on initialization to set initial values. Be careful with the names of the fields you have declared in the form and model.

```
def create_cancel(request,id):
    booking_obj = get_object_or_404(Ticketing,id=id)
     
    # set initial data here
    initial_data = {'title': 'Title' }
    form = CancelForm(initial=data)
    

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CancelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.admin = request.user
            obj.ticket= booking_obj
            obj.save()
            return redirect('cancel:create' ,booking_obj.id)

     context = {
    '    booking_obj':booking_obj,'form':form
     }
     return render(request,'cancel/create.html',context)
```